# Sequencer not playing in background

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

I'm building an iOS app with audiokit that plays a midi file with the AppleSequencer (which plays a sampler). Everything works as expected.

But i'd like to let the app play the music in the background. Have everything setup to make this possible. And the audio is playing nicely (fading out).

But it seems the sequencer is paused/stopped in the background. At least there are no midi notes coming through anymore.

I tried a test to play a note every 5 seconds (with a scheduledTimer) and this keeps on playing in the background, so nothing is wrong with the audio.

My question, how can i let the sequencer play while the app is in the background?

Comment: I had the same issue and could never make it work. If you found an answer I’d love to know how to do it.

Comment: No not found an answer that uses the AppleSeqeuncer. I'm refacturing my app so won't need the sequencer. But if someone has a solution with the sequencer that would be realy nice though.